# (the omission of ) articles in front of dinner/ class?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I read on Purdue OWL names of languages/nationalities, names of sports and names of academic subjects do not require articles. But what are the other situations?

To be more specific, I saw the sentence "I'd been sitting here for 10 minutes before class started" in a grammar book, and I wonder why there was no article in front of class.

When I asked the writing lab, I got the answer that it's convention. I got another example from the person who answered my question, saying other common usages including "I'm waiting for dinner to start" or "Let's leave after dessert" are both correct.

Is it just convention? Is there any rule behind it? Thank you!!

Comment: No particular rule. Americans, more than British speakers, are inclined to drop the article in the examples you give. That's with the exception of *dinner*. No one would use the article in the context you gave for that. But there are situations in which I would say *the dinner*. E.g. 'I'm not a member of the golf club and I am not invited to their AGM, but I can if I wish stay for *the dinner*.'

Comment: The article tends to be used when referring to a specific dinner, but not when referring to it more generically.

Comment: @WS2: I've no prior knowledge of whether AmE is more likely to drop the article in such contexts, but I do note that with the comparable [*before {the} term starts*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=before+term+starts%2Cbefore+the+term+starts&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbefore%20term%20starts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbefore%20the%20term%20starts%3B%2Cc0), the AmE corpus shows both forms used about equally. But only the version *without* the article occurs often enough in BrE to actually chart.

Comment: The difference between rules and conventions being? I assume you want a 'rule' that makes the whole article-or-not thing seem less crazy. Article usages in English are sadly hard to predict.

Comment: @WS2: I have heard British folks dropping articles from dinner certainly. And note that they also drop them where we wouldn't: we say *in* **the** *hospital* where they would say *in hospital*.

Comment: British English also has "in future" instead of "in the future," though I'm not sure it's the same with the past and the present. That's what makes articles so hard for ESL speakers to get the hang of. There are plenty of words where Americans drop the article while Brits retain it, plenty of words where Brits drop the article while Americans retain it, and plenty of other words that just depend on the context of the sentence.

Comment: @Robusto Americans, I sense, misunderstand the way that in Britain we use *hospital, prison, school, university etc* without the article. If I say *she is in hospital*, I mean she is a patient and I do not refer to any particular hospital merely to her status of 'in hospital'. But doctors, nurses, administrators work *at THE hospital*, or *in A hospital*. (Continued)

Comment: @Robusto (B Fwd.) Similarly if I hear that someone is *in prison*, then I know that they are an inmate. A prison warder works *in a prison* or *at the local prison*. This same rule applies to *school* (pupil), *university* (student). A lecturer teaches *at THE university*, but his son (a student) is *at university*.

Comment: @WS2: Americans too say *in prison*, *at school*, etc. We differ with BrE mainly in the hospital and university usages. We just wouldn't use the word *university* but we would drop the article. "My son is at college." or "My son goes to college."

Comment: @Robusto Yes - saying someone is *in hospital*, *in prison*, or *at university*, discloses nothing about which hospital, type of hospital etc. It is merely a explanation of their living status. Increasingly large numbers are in *care homes*. But we always use an indefinite article. 'Poor Charles has Alzheimer's and is in *a care home*'. Though the article is sometimes dropped with *She's in residential care*, or simply *she's in care*.. I still get puzzled as to why Americans use a *definite* article with hospital - I could understand an indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

There is no convention for knowing which nouns are able to exclude an article.  There are several additional categories that can be article-free, but again it is just a helpful generalization.  Almost all of them are perfectly capable of having a definite or indefinite article depending on the sentence.

Locations:

> At camp, we built a fire.  The camp was set on fire!  I want to go to a nicer camp next year.

Meals:

> We had roast for dinner. Unfortunately, the roast burned. It always burns whenever I cook a roast.

Transportation:

> You'll get there faster by car than train. You can take the car. I prefer the comforts of a train.

Uncountables (the indefinite form is generally presented without article):

> I like to drink water with my meals. Please pass the water.

This is by no means a comprehensive list.  Some nouns are found mostly without articles.  These are the ones you mentioned in your question: nationalities, sports, subjects, but also seasons and holidays.

Seasons:

> Leaves typically fall off trees during autumn.

Holidays:

> I prefer not to work on Christmas.

Language/Nationality:

> Unfortunately, like so many things in English, the usage does not follow a very strict set of rules.